# 504 Gateway time out php

Tags: php

i'm running script(svc/rest services) that request a server  which response me a XML string.. this request is going through an intermediate server.

My aim is to fetch the details of guests o.e. rooms which will be response..

but after certain number of request i am getting 504 gateway out and only about 40 rooms are able to retreived

1: file...source hots

```
$ROOMS = ["301","302","304","305","306","307","308","309","310",
          "311","312","314","315","316","317","318","319","320",
          "401","402","403","404","405","406","407","408","409",
          "410","411","412","414","415","416","802","802","802",
          "802","802","802","802","802","802","802","802","802",
          "802","802","802","802","802","802","802","802","802",
          "802","802","802","802","802","802","802","802"
];
// all rooms more than 75

for ($x = 0; $x < count($ROOMS); $x++){
    $end_point = "https://www.innkeyapp.com/SerRest.svc/GetOccupiedRoomData";
    $sharedkey = "2diSq8bjZ4N3ZR4XB5KXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
    $url       = 'https://eastern-services.com/innkeyPMS_room_ststus.php';
    $room_no   = $ROOMS[$x];
    $postdata  = http_build_query([
        'end_point' => $end_point,
        'room_no'   => $room_no,
        'sharedkey' => $sharedkey
    ]);  
    $opts = [
        'http' => [
            'method'  => 'POST',
            'content' => $postdata
        ]
    ];
    $context   = stream_context_create($opts);   
    $result    = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);  
    $arrayData = json_decode($result,true);  
    if (empty($arrayData)) {  
        // Redirect('failure.php?msg=Error in service');  
        echo "Error in Service";  
        exit();  
    }  
    print_r($arrayData);  
    echo $room_no."Added";  
}
```

2: file....    innkeyPMS_room_ststus.php i.e. intermediate host.

```
$room_no   = $post_var['room_no'];
$end_point = $post_var['end_point'];
$sharedkey = $post_var['sharedkey'];

$registerno = '';
$prprtxt    = '';
$validunit  = '';

// echo $post_var;

function curl_get_file_contents($URL)
{
    return file_get_contents($URL);
}

$xmlString = curl_get_file_contents(
     $end_point.'sharedkey='.$sharedkey.'=&roomno='.$room_no
);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xmlString);
header("Content-Type: application/json");
echo json_encode($xml);
```

why this connection is getting lost or why its showing 504 gateway time out?

Comment: The reverse proxy in front of your hosting is timing out waiting for your calls to finish, look into using curl_multi or reduce the calls or increase the time the proxy waits..

Comment: Or dont to it inline, use a cronjob or task queue..

Comment: Okay, it does work fine with one room.... when i goto make this one after one using array...then after 40 counts its giving this error.  any solution?  like terminate and reconnce.. ?

Comment: I've mentioned solutions in my first comment, plus you could do individual calls to the API and update the UI with ajax so as not to do too much serverside on a single request even things like server-sent-events to feed the room states back as their checked. What your doing is inefficient and hammering that API on each request when you could add caching, and using curl multi which will speed things up considerably..

Comment: Thank you, will proceed accordingly.